# Upload images between texts in CKeditor

Tags: media, wysiwyg

I have a user manual in my site using Drupal 6, Which was created using book module. I use [CKEditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) as the editor and I want to upload images between the paragraphs. CKeditor asks for url to upload images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Insert](https://drupal.org/project/insert) is must for easy insertion of image links in the text of node. You case insert using [Colorbox](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox) or lightbox2. It can also insert using image styles you may have defined.

Make sure you do the screencast mentioned in the Insert module page.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding clearly your question, then you want to upload images using *ckeditor*.

You can use [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce) module which provide the functionality to upload image.

> IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal
>   directories and quota.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple with Wysiwyg should just add this module [IMCE Wysiwyg bridge](https://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg)
go to admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/ and edit for example FULL HTML then check IMCE image in buttons and plugins